# Get the key name of an array in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this array of values for printing in a table

```
 array(4) {

      ["ayel.bokbok"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["/app_dev.php/index/"]=>
        int(2)
      }
      ["ryhel1120"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["/app_dev.php/index/"]=>
        int(47)
        ["/app_dev.php/users/"]=>
        int(84)
      }
      ["ariel.alvarez"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["/app_dev.php/users/"]=>
        int(3)
      }
      ["rainercedric23"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["/app_local.php/admin/analytics"]=>
        int(338)
        ["/app_local.php/index/"]=>
        int(7)
        ["/app_local.php/users/"]=>
        int(13)
      }
```

how can i print the `ayel.bokbok` in twig because in this code `{%key,value in foo%}` twig it only prints the index and not the key name of the key.

@ponciste this is what {{dump(array)}} prints in the twig:

> array(1) {
>
> [0]=> array(4)
>
> ```
> { ["ariel.alvarez"]=> array(2) 
>
>     { ["/app_dev.php/index/"]=> int(1) 
>
>       ["/app_dev.php/users/"]=> int(3) } 
>
>   ["ayel.bokbok"]=> array(1) 
>
>     { ["/app_dev.php/index/"]=> int(4) } 
>
>   ["ryhel1120"]=> array(2) 
>
>     { ["/app_dev.php/index/"]=> int(58) 
>
>       ["/app_dev.php/users/"]=> int(121) } 
>
>   ["rainercedric23"]=> array(3) 
>
>     { ["/app_local.php/admin/analytics"]=> int(312) 
>
>       ["/app_local.php/index/"]=> int(7) ["/app_local.php/users/"]=> int(8) } 
>
>  } }
> ```

this is the code from the controller:

```
<?php

namespace foo\BarBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AnalyticsController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        $Gapi = $this->container->get('bti_rep_sys.gapiManager')->GapiGetOverview();
        $Gapifiltered = $this->container->get('bti_rep_sys.gapiManager')->GapiGetFilter();


    return $this->render('fooBarBundle:Analytics:index.html.twig', array('gapidata' => $Gapi, 'gapidatafiltered'=> $Gapifiltered));
  }

}
```

this is my code for the index.html.twig:

```
{%extends "fooBarBundle::layout.html.twig"%}
{%block body%}
{%include "fooBarBundle:Analytics:GoogleCharts.js.twig"%}

<h1>Analytics Report </h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="float-left" id="chart_div_bar"></div>
    <div class="float-right" id="chart_div_pie"></div>
</div>

<div class="right-align">(Updated as of {{"now"|date('d/m/Y')}})</div>
{{ dump(gapidatafiltered) }} // for dumping of data
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: that's exaclty what {{ dump(array) }} prints?

Comment: post also your php where you set your array

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to get the `/app_dev.php/index/` string then this might do the trick

```
{% for route,paths in foo %}
    {% for path in paths|keys %}
        {{ path }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how can I iterate the paths? I want to print all the key paths because in your answer in only returns the 1st value of the array.

Comment: @Cedric I've updated the code in my answer to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could use [key](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/keys.html#keys) filter for getting array keys:

```
{% for key in foo|keys %}
    Key: {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

But, as @ponciste mentioned, pleas show us `{{ dump(foo) }}`.

Comment: i'm not sure this is going to fix his issue, because i think there is an error while setting the key in the PHP

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by creating a for loop statement before getting the key names:

```
{% for array in gapidatafiltered %}
    {% for user, key in array%}
      {{user}}
         {%for x,y in key%}
           {{x}}{{y}}
         {%endfor%}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gets all they keys I needed specifically all the username and paths with the int value inside the paths. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This I believe does it, in one go.

```
  {% for item,key in data|keys %}
     <li><a href="{{ key }}">{{ item }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
```